# Javascript : to explicitly send a message to dead letter queue in azure function app which is service bus triggered

Tags: javascript, azure-functions, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

I have service bus triggered azure function app. In the function app based on some condition i want to transfer the message to dead letter queue.

```
const sbClient = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString);
    const receiver = sbClient.createReceiver('chattopic', 'test', {
        receiveMode: "receiveAndDelete"
    });
    console.log(serviceBusMessage);
   await receiver.deadLetterMessage(serviceBusMessage, {
        deadLetterReason: "Error",
        deadLetterErrorDescription: "Error."
    })
```

However i get the following error

```
Result: Failure
Exception: The operation is not supported in 'receiveAndDelete' receive mode.
Stack: Error: The operation is not supported in 'receiveAndDelete' receive mode.
```

I get same error even when i change the receiveMode to peekLock.
Can anyone please help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I think the reason you get this exception is because you are trying to dead letter the messages using the `servicebusClient` but those messages weren't fetched using that service bus client.
- So, to remove this exception we would need the same client used by the service bus trigger to fetch the messages, but that is not available.
- Also, you don't even need to create a service bus client, receiver etc.
  Even throwing an exception will dead letter the message.

```
module.exports = async  function(context, mySbMsg) {
throw new Error('Exception');
}
```

Before sending the message:
[image]

After sending the message:
[image]

Local terminal :
[image]